# installing laravel on ubuntu 13.10

Tags: php, linux, apache, laravel-4

Hi I try to install laravel 4 on my ubuntu 13.10 using the laravel command but when i palce the laravel file in /usr/local/bin I have a problem. For using laravel command I must be super user. There is a way for installing laravel with my user?

Comment: What 'laravel' command/file are you referring to? artisan?

Comment: I download laravel.phar and after that i moved it into the usr/local/bin folder and renamed it into laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install composer this way:

```
php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php
```

and then easily create a laravel project with:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel /path/to/project --prefer-dist
```

this should be possible as normal user without `sudo`.

Happy coding!

Comment: And My old installation of composer,I just delete the file from the usr/local/bin folder?

Comment: when you have installed composer already - and it works - you don't need to install it this way.

Comment: I installed composer but when I moved in /usr/local/bin and I run composer with sudo permission my laravel project folder has as owner root..

Comment: tried `sudo chown -c your_user_name /path/to/project` ?

or `sudo chmod 777 /path/to/project/ -R`

Answer (score 0):

You have to add laravel in your PATH using below command.

```
export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

Now if `$ laravel new blog` doesn't work you can use `$ sudo laravel new blog`

A complete guide is available here on my blog post: http://scriptbaker.com/install-laravel-on-ubuntu/